# Facebook Custom Conversions Aren't Tracking Properly

Tags: wordpress, facebook, pixel

I have set up a custom conversion based on custom event (visit specific landing page hosted on Wordpress). I've made sure it's set up properly and getting traffic as can be seen here:

[image]

and here:

[image]

However, *and this is strange*, the **custom conversion is showing no data in Ads Manager**:

[image]

Looking at the stats from Ads Manager, it seems like it's not getting traffic, when in fact it is. And it must have been from the ads - the landing pages are new and there's no way the traffic would be organic.

Has this something to do with the new IOS14 changes? Or is the custom conversion tracking not working anymore?

I also tested it out in the Pixel Settings and this is the result after visiting the landing page:

[image]

Everything is listed as expected, but it **doesn't say "Processed" or where it was received from with the Custom Conversions**.

I assigned the custom conversions even in my Business Settings -> Custom Conversions, but with no effect yet.

Comment: How do you trigger your custom event from your Wordpress site?